# Правильна ли пунктуация во втором предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

«Какой ты веры?» – спросил через «переводчика» один из гостей. «Никакой! – ответил ему и для острастки добавил: – Коммунист».

Answer (score 2):

1. Если слова автора стоят внутри прямой речи, выделяемой кавычками, то кавычки ставятся только в начале и в конце прямой речи. [« ... ».]
2. Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора стоит восклицательный знак, то после него ставится тире. При этом слова автора пишутся со строчной буквы.
   [*Никакой! — ответил...*]
3. Если в словах автора, находящихся внутри прямой речи, имеются два глагола со значением высказывания, из которых один (*ответил*) относится к первой части прямой речи, а другой (*добавил*) — ко второй, то после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире, причем первое слово второй части пишется с прописной буквы.
   [*...добавил: — Коммунист*]

[§ 50. Слова автора внутри прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=278)

«Никакой! — ответил ему и для острастки добавил: — Коммунист».
Пунктуация в Вашем предложении правильна.